# facebook javascript SDK: FB.Canvas.setAutoResize iFrame not working?

Tags: javascript, facebook

we built a facebook application with ruby/rails and facebooker (iframe application) and are currently stuck with the FB.Canvas.setAutoResize which seems to fail in some cases. using the example from facebook developer docs ( see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ ). the autoresize fails once you enter a page which is higher than 800px - so to say, it just works as long as the canvas gets bigger, not when it gets smaller. anyone has a clue or maybe a workaround?

here is the resizing code piece

```
<div id="fb-root" style="width:1px;height:1px;position:absolute;"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '126342024064822', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(true,100);
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

i am very thankful for any comments or hints, since i am twisting my head around this one for more than a day now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some key things to make sure are set in the application settings:

1. Canvas Settings -> Render Method = iFrame
2. Canvas Settings -> iFrame Size = Resizable
3. Migrations -> new SDK = Enabled

Next adjust your code by adding a timeout (250 seems to work best, but you may want to experiment futther).  I've tested this in FF3.6 and IE7+.  In IE there is a momentary flash of the vertical scrollbar which I'm still trying to fix.

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '12345678910', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
  }, 250);
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: You could maybe fix the scrollbar flash with overflow: hidden on the body.

Comment: I was able to hide the scrollbar flash with overflow:hidden on the body _and_ html.

Comment: FYI, the reason why you need to add overflow:hidden, as I suppose is because of the padding and margin, FB uses JS to calculate the size of your canvas, which is calculated differently by browsers, some do not include the padding and margin in the calcuation.

Comment: setAutoResize will no longer work as it has been renamed to setAutoGrow.  See here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/

Answer (score 7):

the solution is easy!
besides putting FB.Canvas.setAutoResize()
you have to change ur    body   to   body style="overflow:hidden"

it works for me!  now ie8 is ok!!

Answer (score 2):

I'd also like to point out, that you do indeed need your

```
<div id="fb-root">
```

for this to work.