# Facebook Canvas Application iFrame Size Showscrollbars Issue

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-iframe

I am using Facebook C# SDK in my ASP.net application.
I have an iFrame application whose iFrame Size set to Showscrollbars.
[image: Settings]
 The application was working fine till yesterday, but today the iFrame is not stretching to its width (From the documentation Facebook's iFrame width is 760px [Link here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/)). The page in my application's width is set to 95%. So I think its not a width problem in my application.
 [image: Please see this image].
I have to use Showscrollbars option for my application.
  Did facebook Changed any settings for the iFrame Apps? Help please.

**UPDATE** Looks like facebook broke something or they are trying to get rid of scrollbar options. I have to change my application to use AutoResize Option. I made the following changes to my asp.net application and it is working fine except one issue (see at the bottom of the question)

```
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
      FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script>
     FB.init({
                appId: '12345678', //replace with your facebook appid
                cookie: true,
                status: true,
                xfbml: true
              });
  </script>
</body>
```

iFrame stretches vertically when the content increases. That's cool but the
**ISSUE** is [Read Here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024525/facebook-javascript-sdk-fb-canvas-setautoresize-iframe-not-working). I am working on it. If any one figures it out please let me know.

Comment: I have the same problem. Was working fine yesterday :-(

Comment: Facebook has been breaking this for our apps intermittently for a couple weeks now. There's a bug filed with them that they're apparently working to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it with this simple bit of CSS in the iFrame page

body {overflow:hidden;}

everything still fits nicely, with nothing cut off.  just gets rid of those pesky scrollbars!
it certainly sounds like a bug, worked fine in all other browsers but FF 3.6
adding the above also has the advantage of not having the srollbars momentarily show on load.

Comment: Is this CSS fix for ShowScrollbar Option or AutoResize option?

Answer (score 0):

Use code below and it's works on all of my iframe apps :)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({
        appId: '123456789',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();

    FB.Array.forEach([200, 600, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000], function(delay) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            FB.Arbiter.inform("setSize", FB.Canvas._computeContentSize());
        }, delay)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That's working for me when resize needs are getting higher, but if I enter into a big page that resizes a lot and then go to another one which shouldn't need to resize, as it could fit whitout scrollbars, it doesn´t does, scrollbars are still there and my page is huge. Is this happening to all of you? Any solution?